# docker cp returning 'invalid output path' error

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Use-case: copy a file containing some creds from local machine directory to *existing and already created Docker container/volume*

Per the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) on using `docker cp`, I constructed my command line statement like this:

`docker cp mynodered:/Users/<myUserName>/Documents/nodered-volume/creds.json /data/creds.json`

However, I consistently get an error returned:
`invalid output path: directory "/data" does not exist`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I found that **changing** the syntax of the `docker cp` statement to:

`docker cp /Users/<myUserName>/Documents/nodered-volume/creds.json mynodered:/data/creds.json` resolved the issue

**troubleshooting tl;dr**

1. I didnt see this documented anywhere, but the syntax that worked for me was `docker cp <current local filepath> containerName:/<intended container filepath>`
2. Make sure there is **not** a  space between `containerName:` and `/<intended container filepath>`

Answer (score 0):

> However, I consistently get an error returned: invalid output path:
> directory "/data" does not exist

Above error message you're getting since such directory doesn't exists

```
# ensure /data exists if not create directory
mkdir -pv /data

# now copy whatever from container to host directory
docker cp <container-id-or-name>:/absolute/path/of/your/file /data
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay, I should have been more clear: the `/data` directory *did* exist prior to my `docker cp` attempt

Comment: thats correct! I posted my answer below, but Stackoverflow wont let me mark it correct for another day